# bricked mi a2 lite

Tags: rooting, twrp, linux, xiaomi-mi-a2-lite

Today I had a bad idea and decided to try to install Gcam on my A2 lite. So I installed ADB and Fastboot on my PC (linux), then flashed TWRP with the aim of later installing Magisk.

However, something went wrong: whenever I switch on the phone, the phone has consistently not booted to Android, but only to TWRP (which however was working). So I panicked and tried to fix this issue via fastboot, but things did not improve; in fact, they even got worse, as now the phone is unresponsive after TWRP's splash screen.

The only things I can still actively do are shutting the phone on or off, and starting fastboot instead of booting the system (which amounts to booting TWRP after all). Once connected the phone to my PC with a USB cable, ADB does not see the phone, but fastboot does.

I've tried a few things already, including flashing TWRP again and flashing a new system.img I've downloaded from the Xiaomi page, but with no success; Is there any chance to save my phone?

(I've tried to use a Linux porting of MiFlash, but with no success, either).

Comment: May i know how you tried to flash system.img

Comment: I got the file from the rom offered by Xiaomi.

Comment: but how did you flash it? did you use fastboot?

Comment: Yes, I did so. But with no effect, seemingly.

Comment: Did it report any error after your fastboot flash command?

Comment: To be hones, I can't remember. But I've to do it once again, right now, and the outcome is:
...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.020s

Comment: please try running fastboot reboot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94510/discussion-between-helper-and-delio-mugnolo).

Comment: @helper so finally it was your solution: "did you get your system.img from here: http://en.miui.com/download-354.html"

Comment: Good it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Get the system.img from here: http://en.miui.com/getrom-354.html  and flash it